# Why is there an exclamation point before the variable on this conditional statement?

Tags: php

This is the conditional statement:

```
$comments = get_value_of_comments_as_string();

if( !$comments == "on" ){...}
```

What is the purpose of the `!` point before the `$comments` variable especially since `$comments` holds a string.

Edit: this conditional doesn't seem to be a typo as the original coder had like 5 of these conditional statements. all like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

! is the logical negation operator (or not) so basically it changes truthy values to false and falsey values to true.

I'm sure the author's intentions was to be

```
!($comments == "on") // if comments == "on" return false
```

but what his is actually saying is

```
(!$comments) == "on")  // if not comments == "on" ... this test will only succeed if comments is null or an empty string.
```

A much better way to express this is

```
$comments != "on"
```

This behavior is because ! has a higher precedence then == so it will evaluate before the `==`.

Comment: so `if(!$comments == "on")` is equivalent to `if((!$comments) == "on")` ?

Comment: I should correct my answer though because if $comments is an empty string or any other falsey value  the test would be true

Comment: yup.. already tested and saw it only succeeds if $comments is empty/null