# My IF doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Can you tell me why my IF don't work? I'm referring to this:  `if(!$row[12] == '');`
In MySQL: $row[12] have value ''.
I was tring any method I know, but none work.

```
<?php
$nazwa = addSecurity($_GET['mod']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mods WHERE sytemname='$nazwa'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
 if(!$row[12] == '');
 {
    echo '<div>' . $row[12] . '</div><hr style="width:99%;"/><div id="gallery">';

 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($linijka))
        {
            $wyniki[] = $row1['images'];
        }
    foreach($wyniki as $wynik);
    $images = explode(" ", $wynik);
    foreach($images as $image)
        {
            echo '<a href="' . $image . '" rel="gallery" ><img src="' . $image . '"height="100px" /></a> ';
        }
        }
 echo '</div><hr style="width:99%;"/>';
}
?>
```

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: You need to remove the semi-colon from after the if statement.

Comment: Why would you do `if(!$row[12] == '')` over `if($row[12] != '')`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error and unlikely to assist future visitors.

Comment: No no first his $result is empty that's why

Comment: This should explain what's going on http://stackoverflow.com/a/16804692/2364629

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(!$row[12] == '');
```

into

```
if(!$row[12] == '')
```

or

```
if($row[12] != '')
```

Besides that.. it's probably 'systemname', not 'sytemname'...

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes! And remove denial.

```
if($row[12] != "")
{
   ....
```

Or you can still do:

```
if(!empty($row[12]))
{
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your syntax. Starting with your MySQL query, this what your script should look like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mods WHERE systemname='".$nazwa."'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    if($row[12] != '')
    {
        echo "<div>";
        echo $row[12];
        echo "</div><hr style='width:99%;'/><div id='gallery'>";
        $wyniki = array();
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($linijka))
        {
            $wyniki[] = $row1['images'];
        }

        foreach($wyniki as $wynik)
        {
            $images = explode(" ", $wynik);
            foreach($images as $image)
            {
                echo "<a href='$image' rel='gallery'><img src='$image' height='100px' /></a>";
            }
        }
        echo "</div><hr style='width:99%;'/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Still don't work...
http://freetexthost.com/5k660i3p2y
Here is my all code

Comment: @Marcin my mistake, when you have echo followed by "" you don't need to add '' . before and . '' after php variables. Please use my new edit.

Comment: @Marcin Add $wyniki = array(); before the while loop or refer to edit

Answer (score -2):

your $result is empty :
you need to do like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mods WHERE sytemname='".$nazwa."'");
```

Comment: How is that different from what he already has?

Comment: the two quotes , his quesry send $nazma but when u write it how i wrote it send the value of $nazma ,so this is the difference

Comment: @Momo1987 The variable will be parsed in the statement. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: His string is in double-quotes. That will interpolate variables when it's evaluated. The single quotes around `$nazwa` will not affect that at all.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean try it first and if it works for you then i learn today something new, it never work for me like you tell

Comment: @Momo1987 - `echo '$nazwa'` and `echo "$nazwa"` are different. Single quotes around a string treat it as a literal, so it'll just echo out `$nazwa`. Double quotes will check for variables first, so it'll print out the value of the variable instead.

Comment: I know but it never work inside mysql_query for me for example

Comment: Has nothing to do with why the IF statement does not work